# get string value from UIPickerView selected string value from array? (swift/xcode)

Tags: swift, xcode, uipickerview

I have a pickerview in my table view with two selections Male and Female

these are in the array.

```
var MaleFemalePickerViewArray = ["Male","Female"]
```

how to i get the selected string value?

to go

```
let selectedGender = "male"
```

as then i want to go 
place the string value into firebase

like so

```
self.ref.child("Person's Account User").child(userID!).updateChildValues(["Gender": selectedgender])
```

Comment: Can you show some code what you have try out first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UIPickerViewDelegate` ([documented here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate)) has the method `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)` ([documented here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614371-pickerview))

That method is called when the user selects an item in your `UIPickerView` and gives your an index to the row selected by the user.

You can use that index to get the right element from your datasource (`MaleFemalePickerViewArray` in your case).

So:

1. set the `delegate` property of your `UIPickerView` to be your class
2. implement `didSelectRow`
3. bingo :)

You could do something along the lines of:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    guard row < MaleFemalePickerViewArray.count else {
        return
    }

    let selectedGender = MaleFemalePickerViewArray[row].lowercased()

    //insert into firebase or do what ever you please :)
}
```

### Update

Glad it worked...fell free to mark the answer as accepted :)

You ask:

> ...to go to the next view controller i want to guard that the have chosen a gender as at the moment in the VC it appears to be on "male" but it doesnt load to firebase , so i was thinking putting an empty string in the array and saying if selectedgender.text = "" (empty string) alert the user " please select a gender"

Why not use an optional for this?

If you "move" your `selectedGender` out as an optional on your class like so.

```
var selectedGender: String? = nil
```

and then set that in your `didSelectRow:` like so:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    guard row < MaleFemalePickerViewArray.count else {
        return
    }

    selectedGender = MaleFemalePickerViewArray[row].lowercased()
    //insert into firebase or do what ever you please :)
}
```

Then you can do a check when you attempt to go to the next page, something like:

```
func toNext() {
    if selectedGender == nil {
        //The user has not selected a gender, so show an alert and stay on this page
    } else {
        //Onwards
    }
}
```

That way you won't have to use an extra - not needed and irrelevant for your model - value in your array

Hope that helps you.

Comment: thanks that worked, now my question when they click the next button , to go to the next view controller i want to guard that the have chosen a gender as at the moment in the VC it appears to be on "male" but it doesnt load to firebase , so i was thinking putting an empty string in the array and saying if selectedgender.text = "" (empty string) alert the user " please select a gender, any ideas? @pbodsk

Comment: thanks again @pdodsk, though one slight problem , how do i access the let selectedgender in the other func?   as i have func picker view with let selectedgender = "somestring" though i can't access the let selectedgender in the func tonext() {   if selectedgender   } (error unresolved identifier)

Comment: @benpalmer661 selectedGender is moved to be a variable on your ViewController so you can see it in both didSelect: and your next function. Therefore you should not write let selectedGender in your didSelect: function as that creates a new variable but just say selectedGender = MaleFemalePickerViewArray[row].lowercased().